# Getting 400 bad request error in Jquery Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send an Ajax POST request using Jquery but I am having 400 bad request error.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/project/server/rest/subjects",
  data: {
    "subject:title":"Test Name",
    "subject:description":"Creating test subject to check POST method API",
    "sub:tags": ["facebook:work", "facebook:likes"],
    "sampleSize" : 10,
    "values": ["science", "machine-learning"]
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

It Says: Can not build resource from request.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Preliminary check: your browser is pointed to http://localhost:8080/, right?

Comment: maybe not what is causing your issue, but it looks like ["facebook:work, facebook:likes"] should be ["facebook:work", "facebook:likes"]

Comment: Are you using Java and Jersey perhaps?

Comment: I am using JAVA not Jersey..Sling servlet at backend.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Finally, I got the mistake and the reason was I need to stringify the JSON data I was sending. I have to set the content type and datatype in XHR object.
So the correct version is here:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/project/server/rest/subjects",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "subject:title":"Test Name",
    "subject:description":"Creating test subject to check POST method API",
    "sub:tags": ["facebook:work", "facebook:likes"],
    "sampleSize" : 10,
    "values": ["science", "machine-learning"]
  }),
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

May be it will help someone else.

Comment: Could've saved myself an hour of frustrated debugging if I'd found this to begin with. Thanks ;)

Comment: As once said by Thomas Edison, "You haven't failed, you have learnt N ways that won't work" in that hour So be glad that you didn't find it earlier and tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This helped me. Why is this step necessary?

Comment: I had [exactly the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287054/why-does-this-ajax-post-fails-with-elasticsearch) and this is the only place where `JSON.stringify()` is mentioned. Why is it needed?

Comment: 4 years later your answer just helped someone who was tearing their hair out for 2 hours. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue. Though, I'm still lost on why we need to convert the data object into a string. From the jQuery spec, the method should be able to take in a JS PlainObject and automatically convert it into a string.

Comment: If you are using jquery than you can directly use jquery alternative of JSON.stringify  : $.param(data)

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You need to `stringify` the `JSON` data orlse `400 bad request` error occurs as it cannot identify the data.

```
400 Bad Request
```

> Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

Plus you need to add `content type` and `datatype` as well. If not you will encounter `415` error which says `Unsupported Media Type`.

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

Try this.

```
var newData =   {
                  "subject:title":"Test Name",
                  "subject:description":"Creating test subject to check POST method API",
                  "sub:tags": ["facebook:work", "facebook:likes"],
                  "sampleSize" : 10,
                  "values": ["science", "machine-learning"]
                  };

var dataJson = JSON.stringify(newData);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/project/server/rest/subjects",
  data: dataJson,
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

With this way you can modify the data you need with ease. It wont confuse you as it is defined outside the ajax block.

Comment: var dataJson = JSON.stringify(newData);
this is worked for me Thanks @Dhulith De Costa

Comment: Wow, it woked perfectly after i did exactly what u said, thanx :)

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else runs into this. I have a web site that was working fine on the desktop browser but I was getting 400 errors with Android devices.

It turned out to be the anti forgery token.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Cart/AddProduct/",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val(),
            productId: $(this).data("productcode")
        },
```

The problem was that the .Net controller wasn't set up correctly.

I needed to add the attributes to the controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    [DisableCors]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> AddProduct(int productId)
    {
```

The code needs review but for now at least I know what was causing it. 400 error not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old... but just in case somebody faces the error 400, it may also come from the need to post csrfToken as a parameter to the post request.

You have to get name and value from craft in your template :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}";
</script>
```

and pass them in your request

```
data: window.csrfTokenName+"="+window.csrfTokenValue
```

Comment: Nobody has mentioned Craft CMS here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this may be of use to those encountering 400 errors while using AJAX in Wordpress going forward. Even though this question is many years old, the solutions provided have all been programmatic, and I'm sure many have stepped through their code to repeatedly find it's correct, yet continue to find it is not working.

I found dozens of results asking how to resolve "WP AJAX request returning 400 Bad Request" or "WP AJAX request returning 0" and nothing today worked.

Googling "How do I fix 400 bad request on Wordpress?" finally resulted in the answer appearing from https://wp-umbrella.com/troubleshooting/400-bad-request-error-on-wordpress/

> **Clear your Web Browser Cache and Cookies**
>
> You may be surprised, but most 400 errors in WordPress can be fixed by clearing your browser's cache and cookies. Browser caches temporarily store images, scripts, and other parts of websites you visit to speed up your browsing experience.

Clearing both my cache and cookies saw the 400 Bad Request code disappear and results return AJAX results as expected.

Comment: For me worked to clear wodpress cache, login as Admin, select Autoptimize then delete cache, go at end of the page and save and delete cache

Answer (score 0):

You need to build query from "data" object using the following function

```
function buildQuery(obj) {
        var Result= '';
        if(typeof(obj)== 'object') {
            jQuery.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                Result+= (Result) ? '&' : '';
                if(typeof(value)== 'object' && value.length) {
                    for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                        Result+= [key+'[]', encodeURIComponent(value[i])].join('=');
                    }
                } else {
                    Result+= [key, encodeURIComponent(value)].join('=');
                }
            });
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

and then proceed with

```
var data= {
"subject:title":"Test Name",
"subject:description":"Creating test subject to check POST method API",
"sub:tags": ["facebook:work, facebook:likes"],
"sampleSize" : 10,
"values": ["science", "machine-learning"]
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://localhost:8080/project/server/rest/subjects",
  data: buildQuery(data),
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: you don't "have" to, jQuery will attempt to do it for you. Though, if you do build it yourself, you can guarantee it's in the format you want it to be in.

Comment: I don't think I need to build Object using this way. Jquery does this heavy lifting for me. Moreover, whenever data is sent via POST method it is always encoded so we need not use encodeURIComponent over the data to be sent.