# POST Json object using ajax script( Internet Explorer)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I use the following ajax script to POST JSON object.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dialog-placeholder').html('OK');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#dialog-placeholder').html('Bad');
            }
        });
```

In Edge, Firefox, Chrome it works fine. Unfortunately in Internet Explorer it shows me following error.

```
400 Bad Request
The collection of headers 'content-type,accept' is not allowed.
```

Comment: I use Cors in Asp Net Web Api.

Comment: delete contentType attribute.

Comment: is ajax url external?

Comment: @Sourabh, yes I use Web API

Comment: Have you tried with curl? and url is valid?

Comment: @Sourabh Url is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ajax post short-hand instead. Give it a try!

```
$.post
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1c4cx668/

Comment: It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dialog-placeholder').html('OK');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#dialog-placeholder').html('Bad');
            }
        });
```

Comment: The same result.

Comment: I have earlier stringify this to JSON using knockout js.

Comment: same issue  here please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017081/getting-400-bad-request-error-in-jquery-ajax-post

Comment: The same result, i think the problem is with support application/ json in IE

Comment: also it didn't help.

Comment: could you please give url?

Comment: Problem resolved: In ajax script contentType; text/plain.